# Framer Motion: grid item placement

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion

I would like to use properties like grid-area or grid-column with Framer Motion to animate between CSS Grid tracks. With my limited knowledge of Framer Motion I would expect changing these values would trigger an animation, from one spot to the other. I can find alternative ways of doing this, but this would a cleaner option imo, and I'm also just curious if it's a bug or not.

I have a minimal example. The item moves, and you can the slight delay which I guess is where the animation should be, but no animation.

https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-2-layout-animations-forked-2vmqnq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue and I couldn't find any documentation around the topic. My best guess is that CSS grid works only in discrete values. As in, `grid-row-start: 1.2` is not a valid style. It makes sense to me cognitively then why Framer Motion isn't able to animate changes in grid areas/columns/rows.

Comment: No sure an answer per se, but I found an improvement: using the grid-row/col properties directly seems to let Framer take over https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-2-layout-animations-forked-ckpmnp?file=/src/App.js